# Is it safe to disable one display adapter out of two?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, overheating, hp-envy

I've just got a new laptop (HP Envy), it came with a Intel Iris XE graphic card NVIDIA GeForce GTX  1650 Ti with Max-Q Design. However, I sometimes (almost never) play games on it.

[Intel Iris in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6kKO.png)
[NVIDIA in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0Hp.png)

My main issue is that my laptop overheats really fast without any heavy activity even if only desktop is open an nothing else, and as seen in the image the GPU temprature is 46 degrees for the NVIDIA one while it's not even being used.

So is it safe to disable it? If not then is there any other way to make it cooler?

Comment: 46 degrees is harmless and may just be the ambient temperature inside the case.

Comment: 46C is not really hot at all.  You should start getting concerned when it starts running above something like 70C.  Hardware throttling won't start typically until around 90C.

Comment: OKay, but why does it get hot even if it's being utilized 0%?

Comment: Because there are components near to it that radiate heat? Why do *you* get hotter when you move near a fireplace?

Comment: Disable it.....what may wrong?